# iOS UIView - Different rounding radius for each of the 4 corners

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, cgpath

How can I set a completely different rounding radius for each of the 4 corners of a UIView?

UIBezierPath allows me to set ONE value for one or more specific corners, but not a different value for each corner.

I think in theory it should be possible with a custom CGPath but I'm unable to implement it.

Comment: Have you *tried* to do it with CGPath? If so, show the code that you've tried, and explain where you're having trouble with it.

Comment: I experimented with it for a few hours but couldn't get anywhere and deleted the code (unfortunately) as it was nowhere near a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try - you can paste it directly into a Playground page and see how it works:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

extension Int {
    var degreesToRadians: Double { return Double(self) * .pi / 180 }
}
extension FloatingPoint {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { return self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { return self * 180 / .pi }
}

class VariableCornerRadiusView: UIView  {

    var upperLeftCornerRadius:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    var upperRightCornerRadius:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    var lowerLeftCornerRadius:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    var lowerRightCornerRadius:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }


    func layoutMask() -> Void {

        var pt = CGPoint.zero

        let myBezier = UIBezierPath()

        pt.x = upperLeftCornerRadius
        pt.y = 0

        myBezier.move(to: pt)

        pt.x = bounds.width - upperRightCornerRadius
        pt.y = 0

        myBezier.addLine(to: pt)

        pt.x = bounds.width - upperRightCornerRadius
        pt.y = upperRightCornerRadius

        myBezier.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: upperRightCornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(270.degreesToRadians), endAngle: CGFloat(0.degreesToRadians), clockwise: true)

        pt.x = bounds.width
        pt.y = bounds.height - lowerRightCornerRadius

        myBezier.addLine(to: pt)

        pt.x = bounds.width - lowerRightCornerRadius
        pt.y = bounds.height - lowerRightCornerRadius

        myBezier.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: lowerRightCornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(0.degreesToRadians), endAngle: CGFloat(90.degreesToRadians), clockwise: true)

        pt.x = lowerLeftCornerRadius
        pt.y = bounds.height

        myBezier.addLine(to: pt)

        pt.x = lowerLeftCornerRadius
        pt.y = bounds.height - lowerLeftCornerRadius

        myBezier.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: lowerLeftCornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(90.degreesToRadians), endAngle: CGFloat(180.degreesToRadians), clockwise: true)

        pt.x = 0
        pt.y = upperLeftCornerRadius

        myBezier.addLine(to: pt)

        pt.x = upperLeftCornerRadius
        pt.y = upperLeftCornerRadius

        myBezier.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: upperLeftCornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(180.degreesToRadians), endAngle: CGFloat(270.degreesToRadians), clockwise: true)

        myBezier.close()

        let maskForPath = CAShapeLayer()
        maskForPath.path = myBezier.cgPath
        layer.mask = maskForPath

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layoutMask()
    }

}

var testSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)

// set up an orange view to hold it...
let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 260))

containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

// create a VariableCornerRadiusView, just a little smaller than the container view
let TestView = VariableCornerRadiusView(frame: containerView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 20))

// set different radius for each corner
TestView.upperLeftCornerRadius = 20.0
TestView.upperRightCornerRadius = 40.0
TestView.lowerRightCornerRadius = 60.0
TestView.lowerLeftCornerRadius = 80.0

// give it a blue background
TestView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

// add it to the container
containerView.addSubview(TestView)

// show it
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
```

Result should look like this:

[image]

---

**Edit** another approach... Using a filled shape layer (instead of a mask) and a shadow:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

extension Int {
    var degreesToRadians: Double { return Double(self) * .pi / 180 }
}
extension FloatingPoint {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { return self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { return self * 180 / .pi }
}

class VariableCornerRadiusShadowView: UIView  {

    var upperLeftCornerRadius:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    var upperRightCornerRadius:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    var lowerLeftCornerRadius:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    var lowerRightCornerRadius:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    var fillColor: UIColor = .white {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    var shadowColor: UIColor = .black {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    var shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0) {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.5 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 8.0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    let theShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {
        layer.addSublayer(theShapeLayer)
    }

    func layoutShape() -> Void {

        var pt = CGPoint.zero

        let myBezier = UIBezierPath()

        pt.x = upperLeftCornerRadius
        pt.y = 0

        myBezier.move(to: pt)

        pt.x = bounds.width - upperRightCornerRadius
        pt.y = 0

        myBezier.addLine(to: pt)

        pt.x = bounds.width - upperRightCornerRadius
        pt.y = upperRightCornerRadius

        myBezier.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: upperRightCornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(270.degreesToRadians), endAngle: CGFloat(0.degreesToRadians), clockwise: true)

        pt.x = bounds.width
        pt.y = bounds.height - lowerRightCornerRadius

        myBezier.addLine(to: pt)

        pt.x = bounds.width - lowerRightCornerRadius
        pt.y = bounds.height - lowerRightCornerRadius

        myBezier.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: lowerRightCornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(0.degreesToRadians), endAngle: CGFloat(90.degreesToRadians), clockwise: true)

        pt.x = lowerLeftCornerRadius
        pt.y = bounds.height

        myBezier.addLine(to: pt)

        pt.x = lowerLeftCornerRadius
        pt.y = bounds.height - lowerLeftCornerRadius

        myBezier.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: lowerLeftCornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(90.degreesToRadians), endAngle: CGFloat(180.degreesToRadians), clockwise: true)

        pt.x = 0
        pt.y = upperLeftCornerRadius

        myBezier.addLine(to: pt)

        pt.x = upperLeftCornerRadius
        pt.y = upperLeftCornerRadius

        myBezier.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: upperLeftCornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(180.degreesToRadians), endAngle: CGFloat(270.degreesToRadians), clockwise: true)

        myBezier.close()

        theShapeLayer.path = myBezier.cgPath
        theShapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor

        layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
        layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layoutShape()
    }

}

var testSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)

// set up an orange "container" view to hold it...
let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 260))

containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

let sampleView = VariableCornerRadiusShadowView(frame: containerView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 20))

// set different radius for each corner
sampleView.upperLeftCornerRadius = 20.0
sampleView.upperRightCornerRadius = 40.0
sampleView.lowerRightCornerRadius = 60.0
sampleView.lowerLeftCornerRadius = 80.0

// if we want to adjust defaults
//sampleView.fillColor = .green
//sampleView.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 4)
//sampleView.shadowRadius = 4  // not quite so "fuzzy"
//sampleView.shadowOpacity = 0.8

// add view to container
containerView.addSubview(sampleView)

// show it
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
```

Result with "default" properties:

[image]

Result with properties changed to:

```
.fillColor = .green
.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 4)
.shadowRadius = 4  // not quite so "fuzzy"
.shadowOpacity = 0.8
```

[image]

---

**Edit 2** -

This version is now `@IBDesignable`, with some properties renamed to show better in IB. Also added border width and color:

```
@IBDesignable
class VariableCornerRadiusShadowView: UIView  {

    @IBInspectable
    var radTopLeft:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var radTopRright:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var radBotLeft:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var radBotRright:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var fillColor: UIColor = .white {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor = .clear {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowColor: UIColor = .black {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowXOffset: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowYOffset: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.5 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 8.0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    let theShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        layer.addSublayer(theShapeLayer)
    }

    func layoutShape() -> Void {

        var pt = CGPoint.zero

        let myBezier = UIBezierPath()

        pt.x = radTopLeft
        pt.y = 0

        myBezier.move(to: pt)

        pt.x = bounds.width - radTopRright
        pt.y = 0

        myBezier.addLine(to: pt)

        pt.x = bounds.width - radTopRright
        pt.y = radTopRright

        myBezier.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: radTopRright, startAngle: .pi * 1.5, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)

        pt.x = bounds.width
        pt.y = bounds.height - radBotRright

        myBezier.addLine(to: pt)

        pt.x = bounds.width - radBotRright
        pt.y = bounds.height - radBotRright

        myBezier.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: radBotRright, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 0.5, clockwise: true)

        pt.x = radBotLeft
        pt.y = bounds.height

        myBezier.addLine(to: pt)

        pt.x = radBotLeft
        pt.y = bounds.height - radBotLeft

        myBezier.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: radBotLeft, startAngle: .pi * 0.5, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true)

        pt.x = 0
        pt.y = radTopLeft

        myBezier.addLine(to: pt)

        pt.x = radTopLeft
        pt.y = radTopLeft

        myBezier.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: radTopLeft, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: .pi * 1.5, clockwise: true)

        myBezier.close()

        theShapeLayer.path = myBezier.cgPath
        theShapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor

        theShapeLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        theShapeLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth

        layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowXOffset, height: shadowYOffset)
        layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layoutShape()
    }

}
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks for your help (and advice).

Comment: @Maulikshah - sorry, I assumed you would use those extensions from the first answer. They've now been added to the edit.

Comment: IN playground working but in code not working just display shadow not display corner radius ...

Comment: can you provide ibdesignable class?

Comment: copy and paste code nothing change.. just set property like you. and same code copy and paste in playground it's working but in real code shadow works but corner radius not work..

Comment: also check copy pasted code in playground it is also worked.

Comment: @Maulikshah - *"can you provide ibdesignable class?"* Stack Overflow is not a "please do my work for me" site. That said, since it took only about 5 minutes, see **Edit 2** of my answer for a `@IBDesignable` version.

Comment: Finally it's done..Good work....But What is the issue playground work properly and main project don't.

Comment: @Maulikshah - It might be simply that you didn't give the view a clear background, or you failed to set the class properly, or something else.. Otherwise, since it worked fine for me  - both by setting the custom class for a Storyboard view and by creating it via code only - I'd have to see what you were trying in order to figure out what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a convenience initializer for `UIBezierPath` with distinct corner radii. When all radii are equals, it should give you the same path as `UIBezierPath(roundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:)`.

```
extension UIBezierPath {
    convenience init(roundedRect bounds: CGRect,
                     cornerRadii radii: (topLeft: CGFloat, topRight: CGFloat, bottomLeft: CGFloat, bottomRight: CGFloat)) {
        self.init()
        func point(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
            return CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + x, y: bounds.origin.y + y)
        }
        move(to: point(x: radii.topLeft, y: 0))
        addLine(to: point(x: bounds.width - radii.topRight, y: 0))
        addArc(withCenter: point(x: bounds.width - radii.topRight, y: radii.topRight),
               radius: radii.topRight, startAngle: .pi * 1.5, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
        addLine(to: point(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height - radii.bottomRight))
        addArc(withCenter: point(x: bounds.width - radii.bottomRight, y: bounds.height - radii.bottomRight),
               radius: radii.bottomRight, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 0.5, clockwise: true)
        addLine(to: point(x: radii.bottomLeft, y: bounds.height))
        addArc(withCenter: point(x: radii.bottomLeft, y: bounds.height - radii.bottomLeft),
               radius: radii.bottomLeft, startAngle: .pi * 0.5, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true)
        addLine(to: point(x: 0, y: radii.topLeft))
        addArc(withCenter: point(x: radii.topLeft, y: radii.topLeft),
               radius: radii.topLeft, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: .pi * 1.5, clockwise: true)
        close()
    }
}
```

You may easily use it for masking or other purposes:

```
extension UIView {
    func layoutMask(cornerRadii radii: (topLeft: CGFloat, topRight: CGFloat, bottomLeft: CGFloat, bottomRight: CGFloat)) {
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadii: radii).cgPath
        layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```